# Where can i find the ubuntu-one brand (logo)?

Tags: ubuntu-one, application-development

In order to put some contents into ubuntu one, i'm looking for the ubuntu-one brand. I found this [website](http://design.ubuntu.com/assets/ubuntu-logo), but they aren't talking about ubuntu-one.
Does someone know where i can find it ?

We are participating to the ubuntuappshowdown, so we are looking for an open-source logo.

Comment: Did you tried searching here  http://design.ubuntu.com/downloads and here too http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/ubuntu-brand-guidelines/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the Ubuntu One logo on the Wikimedia Commons site:
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ubuntu_One_Logo_U1.svg

According to Wikimedia, the image does not achieve the threshold of originality required to have a copyright so is in 'Public Domain'. I think it would be perfectly fine to use it unless you use it for marketing/selling your products.

Comment: We'd appreciate it if this logo didn't get used, because it's the old one; I understand that that isn't obvious, of course! I'll update it at wikimedia when we publish the newer ones. As per my answer, please contact me for U1 logos until they're published.

Answer (score 3):

Audrey,

I'm currently in the process of putting all the Ubuntu One brand assets, including logos, online on the U1 app developer site at https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/, but I haven't published them yet. Could I ask you to drop me an email and I can get you the logos you'll need? stuart.langridge@canonical.com

Stuart

app dev lead, Ubuntu One